# Use kubeconfig for helm client install panding

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Im using the helm [SDK](https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3) and it works great, for my testing using the fake option which works(for kubeconfig),

Now when I update the `kubeconfig` to my cluster I notice that during installation the chart is **stuck** on **status pending**,
and it **stuck forever** in this state until I'm deleting & installing it again,(manually)
My question is how to solve this issue with the
**Helm SDK** (via code only) https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3,

I mean wait for a while and if the status is pending after 3 min delete and reinstall it again... or try upgrade before

This is the code

```
    kubeConfigPath, err := findKubeConfig()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println()
    }

    actionConfig := &action.Configuration{
    }

    cfg := cli.New()
    clientGetter := genericclioptions.NewConfigFlags(false)
    clientGetter.KubeConfig = &kubeConfigPath

    actionConfig.Init(clientGetter, "def", "memory", log.Printf)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    chart, err := installation.InstallChart(cfg, "test", "chart1", "./charts/dns", nil, actionConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(chart)
}

func findKubeConfig() (string, error) {
    env := os.Getenv("KUBECONFIG")
    if env != "" {
        return env, nil
    }
    path, err := homedir.Expand("~/.kube/config")
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return path, nil
}
```

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://gist.github.com/int128/a01b044009d407629fbde6985258d74f) might help.

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty - thanks, I've tried it out and the output of the function doesnt match, do you have any other idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the example, I don't know what the `installation` package is but I feel like you would need to use a `Loader` (maybe you are using it in that pkg)

from a quick search over the [github issues](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6910#issuecomment-557106092) I found someone with a similar problem - and they got the same suggestion. here is a derived example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action"
    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/chart/loader"
    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/kube"
    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/release"
    _ "k8s.io/client-go/plugin/pkg/client/auth"
)

func main() {
    chartPath := "./charts/dns"
    chart, err := loader.Load(chartPath)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    kubeconfigPath := findKubeConfig()
    releaseName := "test"
    releaseNamespace := "default"
    actionConfig := new(action.Configuration)
    if err := actionConfig.Init(kube.GetConfig(kubeconfigPath, "", releaseNamespace), releaseNamespace, os.Getenv("HELM_DRIVER"), func(format string, v ...interface{}) {
        fmt.Sprintf(format, v)
    }); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    iCli := action.NewInstall(actionConfig)
    iCli.Namespace = releaseNamespace
    iCli.ReleaseName = releaseName
    rel, err := iCli.Run(chart, nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Successfully installed release: ", rel.Name)
rel.Info.Status
    // check Release Status, feel free to run it in a go routine along the deletetion logic
    upCli := action.NewUpgrade(actionConfig)  
    upgradedRel, err := pollAndUpdate(rel.Info.Status, upCli) // see if its better to just run that code here directly :shrug:

// if we still on pending, then delete it
    if upgradedRel.Info.Status.IsPending() {
      unCli := action.NewUninstall(actionConfig)
      res, err := unCli.Run(rel.Name)
      if err != nil {
          panic(err)
      }
    }
}

func pollAndUpdate(originalRel *release.Release, upgradeCli *action.Upgrade) (*release.Release, error) {
    if !originalRel.Info.Status.IsPending() {
        return originalRel, nil
    }
    c := time.Tick(10 * time.Second) // we gonna time it out besides checking repeatedly
    var rel *release.Release = originalRel
    for _ = range c {
         //check the status and try and upgrade
         for rel.Info.Status.IsPending() { // https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3@v3.5.4/pkg/release#Status.IsPending
             // run the upgrade command you have
             // its this function: https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/pkg/action/upgrade.go#L111
             rel, err := upgradeCli.Run(/*you gotta get all the values this needs*/)
             if err != nil {
                 panic(err)
             }
         }
    }
    return rel, nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks, what about the pending issue :) ?

Comment: if you run it somewhat like this example, does it still get stuck on pending?

Comment: Yes, sometimes its stuck on pending and if I dont delete it manually it stuck forever, so i need a way to handle it with the SDK, any idea?

Comment: yeah, can you try to install it manually and see if it gets stuck as well? I wanna figure out if the issue is in the use of the package or if you are getting an issue with Helm.Ideally we can solve it by not getting to the stuck state right, otherwise we gotta look for a workaround

Comment: I was not able to edit my comment, so second comment:
when you try the manual run, add the `--wait` and the `--debug` flags so we can get a look into it

Comment: this happen also when I install it manually, what I want is to "catch" such secnario and after some time in "pending" state try to upgrade and if it doesnt success run delete and then install, could you provide an example how to do it? if you cannot update the answer you maybe can use https://play.golang.org/p/TBk1_Ze4DmN , thanks !

Comment: @Alberto I added to the edit, trying to handle the pending state for you, there are some missing bits that I left commented, but its just organizing the calls to use your parameters right, I added a short poll for the status and upgrade call, after that, if it still kept in pending, creates the uninstall cli and calls it. lemme know if you are still stuck! we're gonna make it work bud haha

Comment: Thanks, I give you the bounty as the time is ending and your effort is much appreciated , the issue that it doesnt works for me, can you provide the full example  please ?

Comment: Can you please advice?

Comment: @Alberto yes, sorry for the delay, I was solving stuff out here in life haha, will come with a full snippet today

Comment: @Alberto https://play.golang.org/p/LunL8kTioCL this should work. If you want, add more logging to know in which step you are in. If it uninstalls, then you gotta run it again -- what I mean is, it retries the upgrades, but it does not retry the full install from beginning

Comment: I've opend another question regard helm API can you please have a look ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67728786/helm-sdk-download-chart-from-extenanl-repo , thanks!