# Helm SDK download chart from extenanl repository

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to download chart which is located external OCI repository, when I download it using click on the link of the chart and version and provide user and password it works but not with the following code, this is what I tried and get an error

**failed to download "https://fdr.cdn.repositories.amp/artifactory/control-1.0.0.tgz" at version "1.0.0" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)** , if I click on the above link it asks for user and pass (in the browser) and when I provide it (the same in the code) the chart is **downloaded**, any idea why with the code its not working?

This is what I tried

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action"
    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/cli"
    "helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/repo"
)

var config *cli.EnvSettings

func main() {
    config = cli.New()
    re := repo.Entry{
        Name:     "control",
        URL:      "https://fdr.cdn.repositories.amp/artifactory/control",
        Username:              "myuser",
        Password:              "mypass",
    }
    file, err := repo.LoadFile(config.RepositoryConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    file.Update(&re)
    file.WriteFile(config.RepositoryConfig, os.ModeAppend)

    co := action.ChartPathOptions{
        InsecureSkipTLSverify: false,
        RepoURL:               "https://fdr.cdn.repositories.amp/artifactory/control",
        Username:              "myuser",
        Password:              "mypass",
        Version:               "1.0.0",
    }

    fp, err := co.LocateChart("control", config)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(fp)
}
```

While **debug** the code I found **where the error is coming from**  https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/release-3.6/pkg/downloader/chart_downloader.go#L352
it trying to find some cache which doesn't exist in my laptop, how could I disable it or some other solution to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to update your repository before locating the chart.

[This](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/cmd/helm/repo_update.go#L64-L89) is the code the CLI uses to update the repositories.

And [this](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/main/cmd/helm/repo_update.go#L64-L89) is the function that performs the update on the repositories.

Comment: Thanks you have provided the same functions :)